# Distinguish between empty object and null-value when reading from database in Golang

Tags: mysql, go

Suppose there is a table, whose structure we do not know beforehand.
Let's say it looks like this:

```
TABLE foo (
  id int
  title string
  comments string
  extra string
)
```

Now let's say we've inserted a row `insert into foo set id = 42, title = "Title", extra = "Extra"` 
Now, I would like to read this table with the a code similar to:

```
rows,_ := db.Query("select * from foo")
for rows.Next() {
   hold := make([]string,4,4)
   ptrs := make([]interface{},4,4)
   for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
       ptrs[i]= &hold[i]
   }
   rows.Scan(ptrs...)
}
```

The problem with the above code is that the field "Extra" is not read, since `Scan` will stop
reading after the null-value for the "comments"-field. Everything after "title" will be an empty string inside `hold`. How do I distinguish between a null-value and an empty string, then?

EDIT: The comments below do solve the problem. Indeed, by having `hold` to be `[]*string`, we can explicitly check for `hold[i] == nil`-condition. As a sidenote, during the `Scan` it appears to allocate necessary space for `hold`-pointers, under the hood.

Comment: *"The problem with the above code is that the field "Extra" is not read, since Scan will stop reading after the null-value for the "comments"-field."* This is not entirely correct, Scan will stop but it will also return an error which will tell you that it is not possible to read NULL into a string, which means that you should not be scanning columns that can be NULL into plain strings.

Comment: ... so the solution is: for string columns that can be NULL do not use `string` but instead use either `*string` , or `sql.NullString`, or `COALESCE(colname, '')`.